# How to create an infinitely long sequence in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm looking for something like

```
val allInts = (1..).asSequence()
```

so I could, for example

```
allInts.take(5)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
val sequence = generateSequence(1) { it + 1 }
val taken = sequence.take(5);
taken.forEach { println(it) }
```

This is not really infinite, though: it will overflow when Integer.MAX_VALUE is reached.

Answer (score 10):

If you need an infinite sequence you should use the new `sequence` function:

```
val sequence = sequence {
  while (true) {
    yield(someValue())
  }
}
```

**Previous answer**

Use `Int.MAX_VALUE` as the upper bound. You cannot have an integer greater than `Int.MAX_VALUE`.

```
val allInts = (1..Int.MAX_VALUE).asSequence()
```

Answer (score 10):

JB's answer is good but you could also go with

```
generateSequence(1, Int::inc)
```

if you're into the whole brevity thing.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37008786/2987755), you would need a function which will generate someValue all the time sequence is invoked, this answer provides one of the implementation which will generate infinite many values.
e.g. Characters from a String and you can write function as

```kotlin
var index = -1L
val seq = generateSequence {
  val length = "instructions".length
  "instructions"[(++index % length).toInt()].toString() //.toString() will convert char to String
}
.take(10000) // just for printing 10000 chars
seq.forEach { println(it) }
```

This will generate Strings and Heap space size is the limiting factor.